# Twitter Bootstrap fading warning

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, warnings

I am still very new to the coding world so I apologize in advance! I am trying to get a "warning" to display after clicking the "Save" button. I realize the issue may be in the javascript code as well. Currently I only see a green alert block as the page is rendered. I would like that to only display once the save button is pressed and fade out after a few seconds.
 My JS code looks like this:

```
        save: function () {
        var that = this;
        that.paymentTypes.commit();
        that.originalData.Values = that.paymentTypes();

        http.put(that.url, that.originalData).then(function (response) {
            if (response.Id) {
                //that.message('Saved!');
                $(".alert").alert('Saved!');
                $(".alert").alert('close.fade');
            }
        });
    }
```

and my HTML looks like:

```
<h3 data-bind="text: displayName"></h3>

<div data-bind="text: message" class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in " />

<form>
<input type="button" value="Add New" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: add" />
<input type="button" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save" />
<input type="button" value="Undo Changes" class="btn" data-bind="click: paymentTypes.undo" />

<table id="paymentTypesTable" class="table table-striped editable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Payment Type Code</th>
            <th>Payment Type Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Is Active</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: paymentTypes.displayMode, foreach: paymentTypes }"></tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `data-bind` attributes, I'm guessing that you're using knockout.  You have a few options for trying to get what you want done.  The first is to use a template with a knockout observableArray, and use setTimeout to remove an alert from the array after a set period of time.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2UnH/

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'alert-template', foreach: alerts}"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="alert-template">
    <div data-bind="text: $data" class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in" ></div>
</script>
```

You're other option is to manually add the alerts to the DOM when needed, and call .alert('close') to remove it.